# Comments unexpectedly truncated in SocialEngine after about 675 characters

Tags: comments, socialengine

When a user posts a comment on our SocialEngine website, the comments are unexpectedly truncated after about 670 characters.

Has anyone experienced this bug before?

The comments are stored in the database in their original untruncated state, so my guess is its' a bug in `modules/Core/controllers/CommentController.php` somewhere. But after scouring the code for several hours, I'm not closer to finding an answer.

Comment: If they are stored in their full state in DB, its def not a `varchar()` or structure thing. I don't know how SocialEngine is built but here are some thoughts: Is there anything using `substr()` (or a form thereof) to trim down comments in that controller? Could it be that the controller mitigating the view is actually somewhere else (such as a page controller)? Could it be that the review is loaded via AJAX on a template and the trimming is happening either in JSON and/or on the page client side?

Comment: Thanks for your help dhaupin. SocialEngine is built on ZendFramework but this comment truncation looks like their own job. The magic happens in /application/libraries/Engine/View/Helper/ViewMore.php and is probably related to the lessLength variable -- see http://pastebin.com/fF4HMi1z. However, it's easier for me just simply to turn off comments truncation altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the bug is in the new line to break rules minifeature. Changing line 24 of /application/libraries/Engine/View/Helper/ViewMore.php:

```
protected $_maxLineBreaks = 4; // Truncate early if more than this nl
```

to 12; fixes the problem for now without removing the functionality entirely. I also noticed that the new line to break rule feature doesn't work as advertised. Changing lines 41-55:

```
// If using line breaks, ensure that there are not too many line breaks
if( $nl2br ) {
  $string = trim(preg_replace('/[\r\n]+/', "\n", $string));
  if( ($c = substr_count($string, "\n")) > $this->_maxLineBreaks) {
    $pos = 0;
    for( $i = 0; $i < $this->_maxLineBreaks; $i++ ) {
      $pos = strpos($string, "\n", $pos + 1);
    }
    if( $pos <= 0 || !is_int($pos) ) {
      $pos = null;
    }
    if( $pos && $pos < $moreLength ) {
      $moreLength = $pos;
    }
  }
}
```

to

```
if( $nl2br ) {
    $string = preg_replace('{(<br[^>]*>\s*)+}', '<br>', nl2br($string));
}
```

and removing lines 56-60 entirely seems to work better.